# classify strongly regular graph with parameter (25,12,5,6)

Tags: graph-theory

how can i classify strongly regular graph with parameter $(25,12,5,6)$?

just i know we have fifteen $SRG(25,12,5,6)$ that two come from latin square(5)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're really looking for are conference graphs of order 25, which come from [symmetric conference matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conference_matrix) of order 26. Your 15 known graphs are the Paulus graphs on 26 nodes, and the 10 are Paulus graphs on 26 nodes. That should be enough to find the answers you want in the literature.

Comment: The strongly regular graphs on 25 vertices have been determined by computer search. I do not believe it has ever been done in any other way.